# Linux Kernel - Data definition has no type or storage class

Tags: linux, kernel, export, definition, symbols

I am working on the Linux Kernel 3.4, and I have the following code:

```
    /* Proximity sensor calibration values */
unsigned int als_kadc;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(als_kadc);
static int __init parse_tag_als_calibration(const struct tag *tag)
{
    als_kadc = tag->u.als_kadc.kadc;

    return 0;
}

__tagtable(ATAG_ALS, parse_tag_als_calibration);
```

but when I build it, it gives me the following error:

```
warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
```

Yes, this is a warning, but it is a forbidden warning, and it is being treated as an error.
The warning is point to the following line in the code:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(als_kadc);
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK. I figured out the problem: I was missing the include for module.h

So, I added this to my code file:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
```

This fixed my problem, because EXPORT_SYMBOL was defined in that header file.